# Linq query with string array in where clause

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have the following LINQ query where clause which isn't returning the expected result. `dtTemp row.Item(0)` has values like `"GE", "LE", "ST", "PL"` while `Stkyard` is a string array with one or more of these values.

I am expecting the below query to filter values based on entry in `Stkyard` but the returned result set has sum of all values in `dtTemp`

```
dtQuery = (From row In dtTemp
           Group row By grp = 
           New With {Key .mth = row.Item(1), Key .mthdesc = row.Item(2)} Into Group, 
           val1 = Sum(Convert.ToDecimal(row.Item(3))), val2 = Sum(Convert.ToDecimal(row.Item(4)))
           Where Group.Any(Function(p) Stkyard.Contains(p.Item(0)))
           Select New With {grp.mth, grp.mthdesc, val1, val2}
           Distinct).ToList
```

Any help?

DonNetFiddle [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WC8LcD)

Comment: Can you share a [.NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) example?

Comment: @aloisdg I have added an example in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've grouped by Month before you filter, and then you filter for any groups where any matches are found.  For example, your Jan 16 Group contains 3 rows, one from each Type, and your filter matches the whole group as it contains one of the items in Stkyard.

To fix this, filter the rows before you group:

```
dtQuery = (From row In dtTemp
       Where Stkyard.Contains(row.Item(0))
       Group row By grp = 
       New With {Key .mth = row.Item(1), Key .mthdesc = row.Item(2)} Into Group, 
       val1 = Sum(Convert.ToDecimal(row.Item(3))), val2 = Sum(Convert.ToDecimal(row.Item(4)))
       Select New With {grp.mth, grp.mthdesc, val1, val2}
       Distinct).ToList
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fHKalk)

Comment: Thank! I was under the impression that Where clause always comes after Group By clause.

Comment: You can use as many wheres as you like.  If you use it after the Group, you're filtering the groups (more like a HAVING in SQL).